# How to secure the use of a PHP script that triggers emails?

Tags: php, security

I build a PHP script to send emails (based on Amazon SES).

So I can make a GET or POST Ajax call to my PHP script:

```
envoi.php?nom=John&email=john@domain.com
```

triggers an email to be sent to john@domain.com.

My website has a registration form which on submit makes a jquery ajax call to the PHP script (website and PHP script are on the same server). I use the script also for other events.

Now I am concerned that this script could obviously be abused if anyone gets hold of its URL.

How can I secure the access to this script?

Comment: If you allow a user to specify the `To:` for the email, the email script **WILL** be abused to send spam. There is no way to secure this, other than having a whitelist of allowable addresses, or hardcoding the address and sending only to that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step1:** When the user opens the registration form, from which he can send mail and passes captcha, set a `$_SESSION` parameter.

```
$_SESSION["mail_allowed"] = true;
```

**Step2:** The request is sent as usual to

```
envoi.php?nom=John&email=john@domain.com
```

**Step3:** Finally, in the mail script, do something like the following:

```
if($_SESSION["mail_allowed"]){
    $_SESSION["mail_allowed"] = false;
    //send mail  
}
else{
    die('File cannot be executed directly');
}
```

This way, the user is allowed to send mail once he opens your page, but cannot execute the mailer script directly.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to protect access to this script and make abuses a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could easily be abused.  There's no solid solution, but a couple ways to protect it come to mind:

- Only allow the link to work for authenticated users that you are sure aren't bots (captcha?)
- Prevent the same IP address from issuing repeated requests.